# Spark - Difference between array() and Array()

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I was converting in the Spark Shell (1.6) a List of strings into an array like this:

```
val mapData = List("column1", "column2", "column3")
val values = array(mapData.map(col): _*)
```

The type of values is:

> values: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array(column1,column2,column3)

Everything fine, but when I start developing in Eclipse I got the error:

> not found: value array

So I changed to this:

```
val values = Array(mapData.map(col): _*)
```

The problem I faced then was that the type of value now changed and the udf which was consuming it doesn't accept this new type:

> values: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(column1, column2,
>   column3)

Why I am not able to use array() in my IDE as in the Shell (what import am I missing)? and why array produce a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` without the Array[] wrapper?

Edit: The udf function:

```
def replaceFirstMapOfArray = 
udf((p: Seq[Map[String, String]], o: Seq[Map[String, String]]) =>
{
    if((null != o && null !=p)){
        if ( o.size == 1 ) p
        else p ++ o.drop(1)
    }else{
        o
    }
})
```

Comment: where is your udf function?

Comment: yeah let me add it

Comment: a udf function would require a column argument to be passed and values in a primitive array . Thats why the error is happening. Shankar's answer below should have answered your confusion

Comment: Yes. Thanks Ramesh for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val mapData = List("column1", "column2", "column3")
val values = array(mapData.map(col): _*)
```

Here,
`Array` or `List` is the collection of objects

where as `array` in `array(mapData.map(col): _*)` is a spark function that creates a new column with type array for the same datatype columns.

For this to be used you need to import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array
```

You can see here about the array

> ```
> /**    
>  * Creates a new array column. The input columns must all have the same data type.  
>  * @group normal_funcs    
>  * @since 1.4.0   
>  */
>
>  @scala.annotation.varargs
>  def array(cols: Column*): Column = withExpr { 
>    CreateArray(cols.map(_.expr)) 
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So how could I modify me code so Eclipse doesn't complain?

Comment: did you import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array`

Comment: Yes was that import. Thanks